# How to position objects with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am doing a maze game so far I have the following code, which reads the positions of a text file the obstacles that must be placed, however I do not have extensive knowledge about pygame to display them on the screen.

```
def set_walls(self, walls):
        walls_length = len(walls)

        for i in range(walls_length):
            # First case is row...
            if "row" in walls[i]:
                row_index = int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", walls[i]))
                print(row_index)
                column_indexes = walls[i+1].split()
                print(column_indexes)
                for index in column_indexes:
                    self.wall_vertical[row_index - 1][int(index) - 1] = 1
            # Second case is column...
            elif "column" in walls[i]:
                column_index = int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", walls[i]))
                row_indexes = walls[i + 1].split()
                for index in row_indexes:
                    self.walls_horizontal[int(index) - 1][column_index - 1] = 1
```

Comment: I would have thought the PyGame manual would cover something like this. Are there any examples in the docs?

Comment: Please post a sample from the text file

Answer (score 0):

If you have the indexes for each wall, you can multiply them by the wall width and height, this should place all the walls in the right places. I can't help much more seeing as how you did not provide a text file sample.

```py
x = x_index * wall_width
y = y_index * wall_height
```